# Newsletter bundle for Sylius (Symfony3)?

Tags: symfony, newsletter, sylius

I was wondering if there was any newsletter bundle existing to add to a Sylius (Symfony3) app ? I searched on the net, but only found Symfony2 bundles.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Did you try, they not working?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official NewsletterBundle for Sylius. You can try using the Symfony2 solutions, but not guaranteed they will work.

You can of course use [SyliusCmsBundle](https://github.com/Lakion/SyliusCmsBundle) and adjust it to newsletter purposes.